# why does my gamepad work via bluetooth but not via usb

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

I have a XBOX ONE S controller, which i want to connect to my PC on which arch linux is running.

I know there is a driver called xpad, which is already installed by default. **My first question is**: As far as I know this driver is only working if you connect the gamepad by USB, is this correct?

The driver (xpad) works as expected when connected by usb. But I want to connect the gamepad via bluetooth. And that works very well too, but I don't understand why! **My second question therefore is**: Which driver does control the gamepad? Since xpad seems not to be the one which drives the gampad via bluetooth (i blacklisted it), which driver is it? **My third question is:** I heard that 'bluez' handles the controller as a HID device, which is some kind of standardizes - is that correct?

Thank you in advance!

By the way: **My last question:** can someone tell me a good book on the topic of driver programming and/or general kernel structure - e.g. i do not really understand how evdec, joydev, xpad, bluez, input and so on communicate. I want to understand exactly what happens when i plug in a usb device or connect it via bluetooth.

Comment: To address your second question, you could try the `lsmod` command before and after you connect the controller and see which driver module gets loaded?